# SVN new repository moved permanentaly

Tags: linux, shell, svn

I created a repository at svn.mysite.com/mysite using the command `$ svnadmin create mysite` from the root of svn.mysite.com.

Without doing anything else, I go to a file on my PC and, using TortoiseSVN, I tried to import this simple test directory `/trunk/test.txt` by right clicking on the trunk directory and selecting import.

In the repo URL field I wrote svn.mysite.com/mysite and it tells me the repo was moved permanently.

What's up with that?

This is the messages I get :

*Import C:\Users\simon\Desktop\New folder\trunk to http://svn.mysite.com/MySite*

*Repository moved permanently to 'http://svn.mysite.com/MySite';*

Comment: My server is hosted on dreamhost if it helps

Comment: I'm assuming you [searched](https://www.google.com/search?q=Repository+moved+permanently&oq=Repository+moved+permanently&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.1140j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8), and none of the results apply?

Comment: Can't find a solution to my problem. Please help

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an apache issue, instead of an SVN issue. If you have access, check your httpd.conf files to ensure there aren't redirects that are cyclical.

Comment: Don't have access to httpd.conf with dreamhost. Isn't there a way I can just ask the server for the actuall path of the repo?